# Revit Dynamo - Python, Get a ModuleNotFoundError when import requests

Tags: python, revit-api

I am a quite new Revit Dynamo user, but I have some years of experience in Python.

I use cPython in Dynamo, and have pip installed requests, pandas and numpy. When importing pandas and numpy no problem occurs, but when I try to import requests then I get ModuleNotFoundError. When I try using the same python in "cmd" no Errors occurs.

I have tried to use the following code below, without any luck.

```
localapp = os.getenv(r'LOCALAPPDATA')
sys.path.append(os.path.join(localapp, r'python-3.8.3-embed-amd64\Lib\site-packages'))
```

Is there a way to solve this problem, so I can use request within Revit Dynamo?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Revit Dynamo, but "ModuleNotFoundErrors" (when the said modules have been installed) invariably mean that you're not running the same python environment that the modules have been installed in.  How are you running this script?  Where is your python binary?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. The problem was that the path I had written in sys.path.append(os.path.join(localapp, r'python-3.8.3-embed-amd64\Lib\site-packages')) was wrong, and even if the path did exist no errors were raised. 
Thanks for your time @ewokx.